# cocos2d-x v3 c++ Drop shadow cocos2d::Sprite

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, shadow

As far as I've found out, cocos doesn't offer a simple filter handling like AS3 for example does.

My situation:
I want to add a realtime shadow to an cocos2d::Sprite.

For example I would like to do something like this (similar to AS3):

```
auto mySprite = Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("myCharacter.png");

DropShadowFilter* dropShadow = new DropShadowFilter();
dropShadow->distance = 0;
dropShadow->angle = 45;
dropShadow->color = 0x333333;
dropShadow->alpha = 1;
dropShadow->blurX = 10;
dropShadow->blurY = 10;
dropShadow->strength = 1;
dropShadow->quality = 15;

mySprite->addFilter(dropShadow);
```

This should add a shadow to my Sprite to achieve an result like this:
[Adobe Drop Shadow Example](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/images/or_sample_shadow.png)

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any built in support for shadows on `Sprites` in Cocos2D-X.

The best option, performance-wise, would be to place your shadows in your sprite images already, instead of calculating and drawing them in the code.

Another option is to sub-class `Sprite` and override the `draw` method so that you duplicate the sprite and apply your effects and draw it below the original.

One possible way to achieve that is with this snippet from [this thread on the Cocos forum](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/shadow-sprites/1214/2). I can't say that I completely follow what this code does with the GL transforms, but you can use this as a starting point to experiment.

```
void CMySprite::draw()
{
  // is_shadow is true if this sprite is to be considered like a shadow sprite, false otherwise.@
  if (is_shadow)
  {
    ccBlendFunc blend;
    // Change the default blending factors to this one.
    blend.src = GL_SRC_ALPHA;
    blend.dst = GL_ONE;
    setBlendFunc( blend );
    // Change the blending equation to thi in order to subtract from the values already written in the frame buffer
    // the ones of the sprite.
    glBlendEquationOES(GL_FUNC_REVERSE_SUBTRACT_OES);
  }

  CCSprite::draw();

  if (is_shadow)
  {
     // The default blending function of cocos2d-x is GL_FUNC_ADD.
    glBlendEquationOES(GL_FUNC_ADD_OES);        
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks in between. I'll check it out.